# What is the solar system orientation to its direction of travel?

Tags: solar-system, astrophysics

I saw the picture and seem incorrectly drawn. Its shows the the edge of the solar system leading facing the Heliosheath. It would not be like NASA to post something as incorrect as this. The solar system should at 60 degrees to the direction of travel?
I'm not sure maybe this picture is correct?
[image]https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/news/784/nasas-voyager-2-probe-enters-interstellar-space/

Comment: What seems “off” to you? Can you be more explicit?

Comment: Your question title is unhelpful (and would be a duplicate), which explains why you are not getting an answer. The problem as I see it, is that you might expect the orientation of the heliosheath to match the direction of travel of the Sun in the galaxy. But the way that the solar system is drawn in your picture suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [image]
>   This is Venus, high in the morning sky, amid the faint pillar of light called the Zodiacal Light. The glow is sunlight reflected off cometary dust in the inner solar system.
>   Above is the centre of the Galaxy area of Sagittarius.  [Alan Dyer](https://amazingsky.net/2014/04/06/venus-in-the-zodiacal-light/)

Since the  [Zodiacal Light](https://www.skyandtelescope.com/astronomy-news/zodiacal-lights-mystery-solved/) lies in the ecliptic plane, the orientation of the Solar system in the Galaxy is something like [this](http://www.xenology.info/Xeno/4.3.htm):

[image]

The Sun moves [through the local interstellar gas cloud approximately into the direction of Scorpio with a speed of about 25 km/sec](http://espg.sr.unh.edu/ism/LISM.html).

Since Scorpio is fairly close to the galactic center (Sagittarius), the Solar System is moving approximately edge-on through the gas cloud as in the NASA diagram.
[image]
(Image: NASA, ESA, Z. Levay (STScI) and A. Fujii)

Comment: How does this address the text of the question and orientation of the heliosheath relative to the ecliptic?

Answer (score 4):

The Sun is heading in the direction of the constellation Hercules: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_apex

It's about 30 degrees above the Ecliptic, meaning the Sun's direction of motion is tilted by about 30 degrees from the plane of Earth's orbit.

Comment: How does this address the question, which concerns the relative orientation of the ecliptic and heliosheath?