# How is the Sun tilted to its orbit around the Milky Way's center?

Tags: the-sun, milky-way, orbital-mechanics, galactic-dynamics, galaxy-center

We know how the Sun is tilted in reference to its planets but how is it tilted to Sagittarius A or its orbit around it? Or isn't it tilted at all?

Comment: It isn't really correct to talk about the Sun's orbit around Sagittarius A*. The gravitational influence of the supermassive black hole isn't relevant in our neck of the woods.

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/28071/in-which-direction-does-the-ecliptic-plane-make-an-angle-of-60-degrees-with-gala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wikipedia page says

> Obliquity 7.25°[2] (to the ecliptic)
>   67.23° (to the galactic plane)

Interesting fact: the sun's layers rotate at different speeds, as well as different rates depending on latitude.