# How are the lines from objects onto the ecliptic called?

Tags: coordinate

See this screenshot from SpaceEngine:

[image]

Many other examples from websites etc. Do they have a name? I couldn't find anything. If I'm not mistaken, those should be the z-coordinate of galactic coordinate system.

Comment: Not a complete answer and there may not be consensus but Horizons calls them "Drop lines" in the orbit viewer; [XEphem](https://xephem.github.io/XEphem/Site/help/xephem.html#mozTocId885716) calls them "legs" (These are in the context of solar system objects with the lines above/below the ecliptic; not sure I'm seen it for stars above/below the galactic equator outside of video games before...)

Comment: I belive they're called stems, based on various google searches pointed me at [3d Stem Plots](https://www.google.com/search?q=3d+stem+plot&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjn1-3vieX4AhVNAM0KHUT6A8kQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=3d+stem+plot&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECCMQJzIECAAQGDIECAAQGDoHCAAQsQMQQzoECAAQQzoICAAQgAQQsQM6BQgAEIAEOgYIABAeEAg6BAgAEB5QzQ5Y-StggTBoAXAAeACAAcsBiAHeDJIBBjAuMTIuMZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=KO3FYuejD82AtAbE9I_IDA&bih=920&biw=1841&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS907US907&hl=en)

Comment: *Interesting question!* What follows is speculation: yes assuming that what's shown are positions in galactic coordinates -- which could be expressed equivalently  in either cartesian, cylindrical or spherical forms -- what is illustrated here looks like the cylindrical coordinate form, and $\mathbf{\hat{z}}$ is most likely going to be defined the same way in cartesian and cylindrical coordinates. But the term for the *draw lines that simply serve to guide the eye* might be "lines of projection" connecting the 3D position with its projection on the $xy$ or $r \theta$ plane.

Comment: Assuming the plane is the ecliptic, it's the z coordinate of the ecliptice coordinate system rather than the galactic system.

Comment: Is it the ecliptic? Or the galactic plane? There's quite a difference! https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28071/16685

Comment: Oh right, sorry about that. I'm specifically interested in galactic coordinates. Although this particular question has probably been answered. Everyone calls those lines differently :D

Comment: This chart library just calls them "bars". http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/scatterplot3d-3d-graphics-r-software-and-data-visualization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently they are called differently in different places. Drop lines, legs or stems.